# Change content of an element by class name with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to apply a hover effect to a grid, so when my mouse passes over the container, a certain grid square will turn black. However, when I mouse over the grid, the entire grid turns black. I have come to realize that when there is more than one element with the same class name, it will change the color of all of them.

```
var hoverContainer = document.getElementById('container');
hoverContainer.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  var colorChange = document.getElementsByClassName('grid-item');
  for(var i = 0; i < colorChange.length; i++){
    colorChange[i].classList.add('hoverColor');
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

I would love a push in the right direction! Thanks!

Comment: You are looping over all the elements and adding the class... don't do that if you don't want all of them to have the class

Comment: Rather than using a loop, only apply the colour change to the desired index. For example, replace your entire `for` loop with `colorChange[3].classList.add('hoverColor');`.

Comment: please post your html

Comment: @ObsidianAge I want the color to affect multiple squares

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try finding the `closest` `.grid-item` to the `target` and changing its `classList`:

```js
var hoverContainer = document.getElementById('container');
hoverContainer.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  const gridItem = e.target.closest('.grid-item');
  if (gridItem) gridItem.classList.add('hoverColor');
});
```

```css
.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.hoverColor {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="grid-item">item</div>
  <div class="grid-item">item</div>
  <div class="grid-item">item</div>
  <div class="grid-item">item</div>
</div>
```

(you'll also need to remove the `hoverColor` after the mouse leaves the `.grid-item`)

But this would be more easily achieved with CSS alone, with `:hover`:

```css
.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.grid-item:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="grid-item">item</div>
  <div class="grid-item">item</div>
  <div class="grid-item">item</div>
  <div class="grid-item">item</div>
</div>
```